Neo4j Spring Data node versioning
I have recently started to work with Neo4j and Spring-Data.
After I have implemented a very basic project with the following node:
@Node
data class Entity(
   @Id var identifier: UUID
)

I have noticed the following error in my log:
2024-07-30T17:10:18.036+02:00  WARN 7520 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.c.m.DefaultNeo4jIsNewStrategy    : Instances of class Entity with an assigned id will always be treated as new without version property

I have tried to add a version to my class as follows:
@Node
data class Entity(
   @Id var identifier: UUID,
   @Version var version: Long? = null
)

But now my code is crashing with the error:
org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: An entity with the required version does not exist.

What am I missing here?

Have you tried making the version non-nullable (and without a null default)? As in: @Version var version: Long. Also, by the way: you should probably use "val" for identifier.

Yes, I have tried the not-nullable type, and with/without the default value of 0 or 1 - all failed.
The var is just a left over, indeed all field of the node are val in my code :)

I believe version should still use a var, so that the value can be auto-incremented.

I think that for it to be auto-incremented it has to be nullable, otherwise I'll need to pass a value there.
Also seems that the problem I have is that I'm loading the nodes from a graph that sorta describe it, and IDK the versions from my CSV file so they clash
